# How to create an object pool to be able to borrow and return objects

Tags: java, pool

I wanted to know that, is it possible to create a pool of objects? So that I can take an object from the pool and once I'm done with the work, I can put it into the pool.

Comment: http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/object_pool/java#

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I wanted to know that, is it possible to create a pool of objects? So that I can take an object from the pool and once I'm done with the work, I can put it into the pool.

It is possible yes.  You can see performance improvements in many situations if the construction of a new object is expensive (like establishing a database connection) or if for other reasons the GC bandwidth is too high (often a problem in Android-land).

Here are some resources that you could use to implement your pool.  You may be able to use Apache's `ObjectPool` right out of the box.

- [Apache Commons ObjectPool](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/)
- [Does this basic Java object pool work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137118/does-this-basic-java-object-pool-work)
- [Object Pool Design Pattern in Java](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/object_pool/java)
- [Google search: java object pool](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java%20object%20pool)

Comment: perfect ! that's what i all wanted :) thanks to @Sergey too !

Comment: Can you help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43860936/create-objects-in-genericobjectpool

Answer (score 2):

Though its late but might be useful.

Following link provides sufficient information and implementation details for creating object pool using apache-commons-pool-2:

https://dzone.com/articles/creating-object-pool-java

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, if each object isn't that heavy weight, and/or you don't mind keeping the object around for each thread, consider ThreadLocal objects.

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/threadlocal.html