# Add objects to object pool

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons, apache-commons-pool

I am trying to add objects to object pool. I am using apache commons pool for this.

My code as is as follows:

```
public ObjectPool<OAuthConsumer> consumerPool;

public ObjectPool<OAuthConsumer> consumerPool;


public void buildConsumerPool(){

    //setting the config path
    PropertyHandler.setConfigPath("/twitter.properties");

    //fetching required tokens for all apps
    String consumerKeySet = PropertyHandler.getProperty("consumerKey");
    String consumerSecretSet = PropertyHandler.getProperty("consumerSecret");
    String accessTokenSet = PropertyHandler.getProperty("accessToken");
    String tokenSecretSet = PropertyHandler.getProperty("tokenSecret");

    String[] splitconsumerKeys = consumerKeySet.split(",");
    String[] splitconsumerSecret = consumerSecretSet.split(".");
    String[] splitaccessToken = accessTokenSet.split(",");
    String[] splittokenSecret = tokenSecretSet.split(".");

    //creating consumer objects for each app
    for (int numberOfAccounts = 0; numberOfAccounts < splitconsumerKeys.length; numberOfAccounts++) {

            String consumerKey = splitconsumerKeys[numberOfAccounts];
            String consumerSecret = splitconsumerSecret[numberOfAccounts];
            String accessToken = splitaccessToken[numberOfAccounts];
            String tokenSecret = splittokenSecret[numberOfAccounts];
            OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
            consumer.setTokenWithSecret(accessToken, tokenSecret);

    }
```

Now i want to add consumer objects to the pool i created before. How do i do that?

Comment: consumerPool.addObject(consume) doesnt do the trick?

Comment: addObject doesnt take a parameter. I checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link for more info on using pools [GenericObjectPool](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/api-1.6/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool.html)

Another post which might help is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924086/how-to-create-an-object-pool-to-be-able-to-borrow-and-return-objects)

You need to associate a factory with your ObjectPool to create objects. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you , i wish it was more straighforward than this. addObject should have done the job. Trying to associate a factory now.

Comment: @NischalHp please consider accepting the answer if you think this helped.

Comment: Done , it actually helped but i ended up not using it.