# Is it possible to allocate and free memory space for a Java Object off-heap?

Tags: java, memory-management

If so please provide an example and also how to free the memory once created.

I imagine it might be possible using the Unsafe instance?

Comment: Is there some reason you'd want to do this?

Comment: Does this article answer the question? http://java.dzone.com/articles/sunmiscunsafe-and-heap-memory

Comment: @CeilingGecko, yes its too reduce the dependancy on the Java garbage collector, in order to reduce latency costs incurred by garbage collection.

Comment: @DNA nope that doesn't help, that shows how to allocate and free Java objects on-heap using the UnSafe instance, and how to allocate and free Java primatives off-heap using the UnSafe instance, but not how to allocate and free Java Objects off-heap.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for a [Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8924086/823393) object.

Essentially - going off-heap is complex and system-dependent. However, if you pre-allocate a pool of objects you can take them and return them atomically. It would certainly ensure a more fixed and predictable latency but it would not *guarantee* it.