# Implementation of Object Pooling Concept in android

Tags: java, android, object-pooling

I am new to android, I need to use Object Pooling in my App, but I don't know enough about it. How might it be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

The implementation on an Android platform would be no different than a typical Java implementation. Maybe you can learn by reading one of these articles:

http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/object_pool

http://www.oodesign.com/object-pool-pattern.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern

or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137118/does-this-basic-java-object-pool-work).